# How to create dynamic HTML header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am creating a dynamic HTML table which has col-span inside,the issue is I am not able to create that col-span headers dynamically. Below is my json

**json**

```
[{
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 451458,
    "discount": 513,
    "GST": 25357,
    "amount": 476426
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 87190,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 4930,
    "amount": 92141
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 109308,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 5966,
    "amount": 115313
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 483194,
    "discount": 471,
    "GST": 28319,
    "amount": 511153
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 109483,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 6198,
    "amount": 115704
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 79305,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 4254,
    "amount": 83597
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 157660,
    "discount": 263,
    "GST": 9944,
    "amount": 167421
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 51059,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 2693,
    "amount": 53775
  }
]
```

`billdate` and `outlet` are parent header inside `outlets` i.e `Jayanagar`,`malleshwaram` and `kolar` here inside this I have other object values i.e `gross`,`discount`,`GST` and  `amount`

- The four `gross`,`discount`,`GST` and  `amount` these are as col-span  which I am creating statically like `innerHTML=gross`
- I want to create them dynamically and not getting the idea how to achieve that

```js
var data = [{
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 451458,
    "discount": 513,
    "GST": 25357,
    "amount": 476426
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 87190,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 4930,
    "amount": 92141
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 109308,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 5966,
    "amount": 115313
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 483194,
    "discount": 471,
    "GST": 28319,
    "amount": 511153
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 109483,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 6198,
    "amount": 115704
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 79305,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 4254,
    "amount": 83597
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 157660,
    "discount": 263,
    "GST": 9944,
    "amount": 167421
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 51059,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 2693,
    "amount": 53775
  }
]
let formatData = function(data) {
  let billdates = [];
  let outlets = [];
  data.forEach(element => {
    if (billdates.indexOf(element.billdate) == -1) {
      billdates.push(element.billdate);
    }
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
    }
  });
  return {
    data: data,
    billdates: billdates,
    outlets: outlets,

  };
};

let renderTable = function(data) {
  billdates = data.billdates;
  outlets = data.outlets;
  data = data.data;
  let tbl = document.getElementById("dailySales");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "BillDate";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  let grandTotal = 0;
  let grandGross = 0;
  let grandDiscount = 0;
  let grandGst = 0;
  let outletWiseTotal = {};
  let outletWiseGross = {};
  let outletWiseDiscount = {};
  let outletWiseGst = {};
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.colSpan = 4;
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  outlets.forEach(element => {

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.colSpan = 4;
    th.innerHTML = element;
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
    outletWiseGross[element] = 0;
    outletWiseDiscount[element] = 0;
    outletWiseGst[element] = 0;
    data.forEach(el => {
      if (el.outlet == element) {
        outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.amount);
        outletWiseGross[element] += parseInt(el.gross);
        outletWiseDiscount[element] += parseInt(el.discount);
        outletWiseGst[element] += parseInt(el.GST);
      }
    });
    grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element]; //calculating totals for Total column
    grandGross += outletWiseGross[element];
    grandDiscount += outletWiseDiscount[element];
    grandGst += outletWiseGst[element];
  });

  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "";
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  for (i = 0; i < outlets.length + 1; i++) {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Discount"; //here statically i am giving the header names
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.classList.add("discount");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "GST"; //here statically i am giving the header names
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.classList.add("gst");

    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Net_Amount"; //here statically i am giving the header names
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.classList.add("netAmount");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Gross_Amount"; //here statically i am giving the header names
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.classList.add("grossAmount");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  }

  headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = "Total";
  td.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(td);

  outlets.forEach(element => { // these are the table rows for each column
    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseGross[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseDiscount[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseGst[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);


  });
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandTotal.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandGst.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandDiscount.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandGross.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);


  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  billdates.forEach(element => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = element;
    row.appendChild(td);

    let total = 0;
    let totalGross = 0;
    let totalDiscount = 0;
    let totalGST = 0;
    outlets.forEach(outlet => {
      let ta = 0;
      let tg = 0;
      let tdi = 0;
      let tgst = 0;
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.billdate == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
          total += parseInt(d.amount);
          totalGross += parseInt(d.gross);
          totalDiscount += parseInt(d.discount);
          totalGST += parseInt(d.GST);
          ta = d.amount;
          tg = d.gross;
          tdi = d.discount;
          tgst = d.GST;
        }
      });

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tg.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tdi.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tgst.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = ta.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);




    });


    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = total.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalGST.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalDiscount.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);



    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalGross.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);


    tbody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tbody);
  tbl.innerHTML = "";
  tbl.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
let formatedData = formatData(data);
renderTable(formatedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div align="left" class="table table-responsive" id="commonDvScroll">
  <table id="dailySales"></table>
</div>
```

- As per requirement `gross`,`discount`,`GST` and  `amount` all these are dynamic they can be 3 sometimes 2 and sometimes 1 so that I am trying to create dynamically
- I have commented the lines in my code where I am creating these as headers

### Edit

Here in the below JSON I have only `discount`,`gst` and `amount` there is no gross so in my table I only want to these three headers as col-span in my table

As solution provided by **@Anilm** doesn't seems to be doing like this

```
[{
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",

    "discount": 513,
    "GST": 25357,
    "amount": 476426
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",

    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 4930,
    "amount": 92141
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",

    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 5966,
    "amount": 115313
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",

    "discount": 471,
    "GST": 28319,
    "amount": 511153
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
           "discount": 0,
    "GST": 6198,
    "amount": 115704
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",

    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 4254,
    "amount": 83597
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",

    "discount": 263,
    "GST": 9944,
    "amount": 167421
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",

    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 2693,
    "amount": 53775
  }
]
```

When in my JSON all `gross`,`Discount`,`Gst` and `Amount` are there then this will be output:

[image: this will be output]

When only `Discount`,`GST` and `Amount` are there then this will be out put:

[image: this will be out put]

Similarly for others also.

These four `gross`,`discount`,`GST`and `amount` are dynamic user is selecting any one,two or all then I want to populate the table.

Comment: I do not really understand this question. Can you create a JSFiddle with the code and a sample HTML you would like to be the result of your code? That would identify the problem.

Comment: If you have missing cells, leave them blank. A table normally has one th per column. If one row has a full set of data and the row after that has a missing cell explain how that's supposed to work.

Comment: @zer00ne  The `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes are pretty common, to cover this exact requirement.

Comment: @LajosArpad i have already created a code snippet, and what are you not understanding?

Comment: @manishthakur the question is not well formed. One needs to read it several times to understand what the exact problem is. I will not do that. If you would like to have better chance of getting help, then you will need to improve your question. I have told you what you need to do. 1. Create a JSFiddle which reproduces the behavior you are talking about. I have seen the code snippet you have given, but I will not create a fiddle for you. You should do that. 2. Give us an example of HTML that should be the result of your code. That would explain the issue better than your words.

Comment: It's not clear when you say, *"As per requirnment gross,discount,GST and  amount all these are dynamic they can be 3 sometimes 2 and sometimes 1 so that i am trying to create dynamically"*. It is not a good practice to change rowspan and colspan to accommodate missing data. The absence of data can be just as important as if it was there. Removing a column implies that the data within the column does not apply anymore (if the reader notices its absence).

Comment: @zer00ne as per requirement i mean here i am getting  `gross,discount,GST and amount` this so according to user selection it can be `discount,GST and amount` ,but `billdate` and `outlet` are going to be common

Comment: @rv7 for what you are talking about? the snippet i have provided that's running fine, The new JSON Object i have uploaded it is not working fine with that,i Have uploaded 2 pictures what i have done and what i am trying to do, at that `for loop` line i am statically defining the col-span headers as per the outlets No +1 because as you can see these for are common in each outlet + one column i.e `Total`

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry. It was some misunderstanding. Well, it is very hard to work with your specific layout. Can you please reduce it to a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

Comment: @rv7 i have almost done the coding just need to make that loop in thead and tbody which is showing those four gross,discount,amount and gst  currently i am doing that four times statically because initially  requirement was that, now user is selecting options and they can select one or more that one

Comment: You are asking us to basically re-write your code to be generic. It's almost like a feature request. You've created this complex structure by hard-coding almost the entire structure. I can only say that the solution will most probably involve `Object.keys` and various array transformation methods.

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb no no i am not asking for whole solution as you can see i have created  some of code by hard-coded structure and as a moderate level `JS` coder i am facing issues to do it as per requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this, I have modified some code from [Anilm's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55689206/4354201) answer. I hope this will work for you.

```js
//added createTable function >> is called on body on load
function createTable(){
    let formatedData = formatData(data);
    renderTable(formatedData);
}   
var hasGross    = false;;
var hasGST      = false;
var hasDiscount = false;
var hasTotal = false;



var data = [{
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "discount": 513,
    "gross": 25357,
    "amount": 476426
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "discount": 0,
    "gross": 4930,
    "amount": 92141
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "discount": 0,
    "gross": 5966,
    "amount": 115313
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "discount": 471,
    "gross": 28319,
    "amount": 511153
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "discount": 0,
    "gross": 6198,
    "amount": 115704
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "discount": 0,
    "gross": 4254,
    "amount": 83597
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "discount": 263,
    "gross": 9944,
    "amount": 167421
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "discount": 0,
    "gross": 2693,
    "amount": 53775
  }
]
let formatData = function(data) {
  let billdates = [];
  let outlets = [];
  let arr=[];

  data.forEach(element => {
    if (billdates.indexOf(element.billdate) == -1) {
      billdates.push(element.billdate);

    }
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
      outlets.push();
        //checking for property of each object of array "data" and if property exists adding to custom_Obj >> then adding to array and returning.
          var jsonObj= {};
      if(element.hasOwnProperty("gross")){
          hasGross = true;
             jsonObj["gross"]=element.gross;
     }
      if(element.hasOwnProperty("discount")){
          hasDiscount = true;
          jsonObj["discount"]=element.discount;
     }
     if(element.hasOwnProperty("GST")){
         hasGST = true;
         jsonObj["GST"]=element.GST;
     }
      if(element.hasOwnProperty("amount")){
          hasTotal = true;
             jsonObj["amount"]=element.amount;
     }


        arr.push(jsonObj);

    }

  });
  return {
    data: data,
    billdates: billdates,
    outlets: outlets,
    arr:arr

  };
}


let renderTable = function(data) {
    var arr=data.arr;
  billdates = data.billdates;
  outlets = data.outlets;

  data = data.data;



  let tbl = document.getElementById("dailySales");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "BillDate";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  let grandTotal = 0;
  let grandGross = 0;
  let grandDiscount = 0;
  let grandGst = 0;
  let outletWiseTotal = {};
  let outletWiseGross = {};
  let outletWiseDiscount = {};
  let outletWiseGst = {};
  th = document.createElement("th");
  let cols = 0;
  if(hasGST){
    cols++;
  }
  if(hasGross){
    cols++
  }
  if(hasDiscount){
    cols++
  }
  if(hasTotal){
    cols++
  }
  th.colSpan = cols;
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  outlets.forEach(element => {

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.colSpan = cols
    th.innerHTML = element;
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
    outletWiseGross[element] = 0;
    outletWiseDiscount[element] = 0;
    outletWiseGst[element] = 0;
    data.forEach(el => {
      if (el.outlet == element) {
        if(hasTotal){
            outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.amount);
        }
        if(hasGross){
          outletWiseGross[element] += parseInt(el.gross);
        }
        if(hasDiscount){
            outletWiseDiscount[element] += parseInt(el.discount);
        }
        if(hasGST){
            outletWiseGst[element] += parseInt(el.GST);
        }
      }
    });
    if(hasTotal){
        grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element]; //calculating totals for Total column
    }
    if(hasGross){
      grandGross += outletWiseGross[element];
    }
    if(hasDiscount){
        grandDiscount += outletWiseDiscount[element];
    }
    if(hasGST){
        grandGst += outletWiseGst[element];
    }
  });

  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "";
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

 //As in this code you are creating "total" column  explicitly and not by json,So to create the header for the total column I am adding this headers to array[0] manually.
 //Otherwise header for that column cannot be populated dynamically.
 //Or you can add a dummy header obj in data array.
var totalcoloumn_obj={};
if(hasGross){
    totalcoloumn_obj.gross = "";
}
if(hasDiscount){
    totalcoloumn_obj.discount = "";
}
if(hasGST){
    totalcoloumn_obj.GST = "";
}
if(hasTotal){
    totalcoloumn_obj.amount = "";
}
//as you showed total column in first, I am shifiting the array index by 1 and adding the total dymmy object at first index.
arr.unshift(totalcoloumn_obj);

//Creating column headers dynamically based on the data array that you declared on the top.


     for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {

         for(var key in arr[j]) {

             var th_dynamic = document.createElement("TH");
            var t = document.createTextNode(key);
            th_dynamic.appendChild(t);
            th_dynamic.classList.add("text-center");
             headerRow.appendChild(th_dynamic);

         }

        }




  headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = "Total";
  td.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(td);

  outlets.forEach(element => { // these are the table rows for each column

    if(hasGross){
        td = document.createElement("th");
        td.innerHTML = outletWiseGross[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
        td.classList.add("text-right");
        headerRow.appendChild(td);
    }

    if(hasDiscount){
        td = document.createElement("th");
        td.innerHTML = outletWiseDiscount[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
        td.classList.add("text-right");
        headerRow.appendChild(td);
    }

    if(hasGST){
        td = document.createElement("th");
        td.innerHTML = outletWiseGst[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
        td.classList.add("text-right");
        headerRow.appendChild(td);
    }

    if(hasTotal){
        td = document.createElement("th");
        td.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
        td.classList.add("text-right");
        headerRow.appendChild(td);
    }


  });
  if(hasTotal){
    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = grandTotal.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);
  }

    if(hasGST){
        td = document.createElement("th");
        td.innerHTML = grandGst.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        td.classList.add("text-right");
        headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);
    }

  if(hasDiscount){
    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = grandDiscount.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);
  }

  if(hasGross)
  {
      td = document.createElement("th");
      td.innerHTML = grandGross.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);
    }


  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  billdates.forEach(element => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = element;
    row.appendChild(td);

    let total = 0;
    let totalGross = 0;
    let totalDiscount = 0;
    let totalGST = 0;
    outlets.forEach(outlet => {
      let ta = 0;
      let tg = 0;
      let tdi = 0;
      let tgst = 0;
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.billdate == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
          if(hasTotal){
            total += parseInt(d.amount);
            ta = d.amount;
          }
          if(hasDiscount){
            totalDiscount += parseInt(d.discount);
            tdi = d.discount;
          }
          if(hasGST){
            totalGST += parseInt(d.GST);
            tgst = d.GST;
          }

          if(hasGross){
            totalGross += parseInt(d.gross);
            tg = d.gross;
          }


        }
      });
        //console.log(tg)
      if(hasGross){
          td = document.createElement("td");
          td.innerHTML = tg.toLocaleString('en-IN');
          td.classList.add("text-right");
          row.appendChild(td);
      }

      if(hasDiscount){
        td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerHTML = tdi.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        td.classList.add("text-right");
        row.appendChild(td);
      }

      if(hasGST){
        td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerHTML = tgst.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        td.classList.add("text-right");
        row.appendChild(td);
      }

      if(hasTotal){
        td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerHTML = ta.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        td.classList.add("text-right");
        row.appendChild(td);
      }




    });


    if(hasTotal){
        td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerHTML = total.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        td.classList.add("text-right");
        row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);
    }

    if(hasGST){
        td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerHTML = totalGST.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        td.classList.add("text-right");
        row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);
    }

    if(hasDiscount){
        td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerHTML = totalDiscount.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        td.classList.add("text-right");
        row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);
    }


    if(hasGross){
        td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerHTML = totalGross.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        td.classList.add("text-right");
        row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);
    }


    tbody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tbody);
  tbl.innerHTML = "";
  tbl.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Utility.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onLoad="createTable();">
    <div align="left" class="table table-responsive" id="commonDvScroll">
      <table id="dailySales"></table>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey sir it has issues 1:> when i am using JSON which has all four `gross`,`Amount`,`Discount` and  `GST` the last column of `Kolar` of last row is not showing up as cell it is empty. 2:> when user is selecting `gross`,`Amount` and  `Gst` then it is throwing error , i think you have done this for only when there is no `gross` in JSON Object Which is wrong  User can select dynamically any of them

Comment: hey nom have you checked the output it is showing something else `kolar`  has only one column and `jayanagar` as 4 columns and Total has only `3` please check

Comment: same issue sir i told you i think you are checking with only gross, now i have gross in my json and i don't have `discount` it throws error, similarly  any one of them can be missing or two can be missing

Comment: hey sir if can you please check out this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56422075/how-to-hide-show-image-on-html-page

Answer (score 3):

```js
//added createTable function >> is called on body on load
function createTable(){
    let formatedData = formatData(data);
    renderTable(formatedData);
}   

var data = [{
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 451458,
    "discount": 513,
    "GST": 25357,
    "amount": 476426
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 87190,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 4930,
    "amount": 92141
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-01",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 109308,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 5966,
    "amount": 115313
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 483194,
    "discount": 471,
    "GST": 28319,
    "amount": 511153
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 109483,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 6198,
    "amount": 115704
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 79305,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 4254,
    "amount": 83597
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 157660,
    "discount": 263,
    "GST": 9944,
    "amount": 167421
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 51059,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 2693,
    "amount": 53775
  }
]
let formatData = function(data) {
  let billdates = [];
  let outlets = [];
  let arr=[];

  data.forEach(element => {
    if (billdates.indexOf(element.billdate) == -1) {
      billdates.push(element.billdate);

    }
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
      outlets.push();
        //checking for property of each object of array "data" and if property exists adding to custom_Obj >> then adding to array and returning.
      var jsonObj= {};
      if(element.hasOwnProperty("gross")){
             jsonObj["gross"]=element.gross;
      }
      if(element.hasOwnProperty("discount")){
          jsonObj["discount"]=element.discount;
      }
      if(element.hasOwnProperty("GST")){
         jsonObj["GST"]=element.GST;
      }
      if(element.hasOwnProperty("amount")){
             jsonObj["amount"]=element.amount;
      }
      arr.push(jsonObj);

    }

  });
  return {
    data: data,
    billdates: billdates,
    outlets: outlets,
    arr:arr

  };
}


let renderTable = function(data) {
  var arr=data.arr;
  billdates = data.billdates;
  outlets = data.outlets;

  data = data.data;



  let tbl = document.getElementById("dailySales");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "BillDate";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  let grandTotal = 0;
  let grandGross = 0;
  let grandDiscount = 0;
  let grandGst = 0;
  let outletWiseTotal = {};
  let outletWiseGross = {};
  let outletWiseDiscount = {};
  let outletWiseGst = {};
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.colSpan = 4;
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  outlets.forEach(element => {

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.colSpan = 4;
    th.innerHTML = element;
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
    outletWiseGross[element] = 0;
    outletWiseDiscount[element] = 0;
    outletWiseGst[element] = 0;
    data.forEach(el => {
      if (el.outlet == element) {
        outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.amount);
        outletWiseGross[element] += parseInt(el.gross);
        outletWiseDiscount[element] += parseInt(el.discount);
        outletWiseGst[element] += parseInt(el.GST);
      }
    });
    grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element]; //calculating totals for Total column
    grandGross += outletWiseGross[element];
    grandDiscount += outletWiseDiscount[element];
    grandGst += outletWiseGst[element];
  });

  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "";
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

 //As in this code you are creating "total" column  explicitly and not by json,So to create the header for the total column I am adding this headers to array[0] manually.
 //Otherwise header for that column cannot be populated dynamically.
 //Or you can add a dummy header obj in data array.
var totalcoloumn_obj={"gross":"","discount":"","GST":"","amount":""};
//as you showed total column in first, I am shifiting the array index by 1 and adding the total dymmy object at first index.
arr.unshift(totalcoloumn_obj);

//Creating column headers dynamically based on the data array that you declared on the top.


     for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {

         for(var key in arr[j]) {

             var th_dynamic = document.createElement("TH");
            var t = document.createTextNode(key);
            th_dynamic.appendChild(t);
            th_dynamic.classList.add("text-center");
             headerRow.appendChild(th_dynamic);

         }

        }




  headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = "Total";
  td.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(td);

  outlets.forEach(element => { // these are the table rows for each column
    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseGross[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseDiscount[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseGst[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);


  });
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandTotal.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandGst.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandDiscount.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandGross.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);


  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  billdates.forEach(element => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = element;
    row.appendChild(td);

    let total = 0;
    let totalGross = 0;
    let totalDiscount = 0;
    let totalGST = 0;
    outlets.forEach(outlet => {
      let ta = 0;
      let tg = 0;
      let tdi = 0;
      let tgst = 0;
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.billdate == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
          total += parseInt(d.amount);
          totalGross += parseInt(d.gross);
          totalDiscount += parseInt(d.discount);
          totalGST += parseInt(d.GST);
          ta = d.amount;
          tg = d.gross;
          tdi = d.discount;
          tgst = d.GST;
        }
      });

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tg.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tdi.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tgst.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = ta.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);




    });


    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = total.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalGST.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalDiscount.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);



    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalGross.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);


    tbody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tbody);
  tbl.innerHTML = "";
  tbl.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Utility.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onLoad="createTable();">
    <div align="left" class="table table-responsive" id="commonDvScroll">
      <table id="dailySales"></table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hey i tried your solution,but it did't work please check with the new JSOn object i have provided in my edit, as the new object doesn't have `gross` but still it shows gross column in table,my json data will be dynamic `gross`,`discount`,`gst` and `amount` are dynamic some times all 4 will be there some times 2 or 3 or one

Comment: In run code snippet it is working as expected as per your previous question.I am not able to understand the exact problem that you want solution for.Please provide a snapshot image of your table how you want it to exactly look like.So that i can modify the solution according to it.

Comment: ok I understood.let me modify the code and I will post the solution

Comment: With the existing code I am finding it difficult.I need to write new code

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`thisSpan = 4;`

`th.setAttribute('colSpan', thisSpan );`

Comment: the colspan 4 you are saying is not fixed

Comment: Your sample code uses a fixed number, but I've edited the above to use a variable instead.

Comment: hey I haven't found any solution with this can you help em out with some code?