# How to Hide / Show Image on HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with Dynamic HTML table in which I am showing my data as in HTML table as my data is in large amount so what I am doing is showing amount of data which will be fixed to one screen, So here i am showing `12` rows at one time then after 5 seconds page refresh hen next 12 and so on, When it reaches to the last page than what I am doing is calling the JSON object again and doing whole process again because in my code that JSON data will be dynamic

**Issue I am facing**

- I have done all the things to refresh page after 5 seconds and calling whole data when it reaches to last page
- Now what I am trying to do is when it is the last page than after that want to show a `image` for 10 `seconds` than again call the whole process
- Now the whole process on first go will be like table will show 12 rows than if there is more data it will show next 12 row of table and when it reaches the last page I want to show an Image for 10 seconds then call the JSON object again to go through whole process again
- In my code I have commented What I am doing where

```js
var tableValue = [{
  "Item Name": "MANCHOW  V SOUP",
  "SellingPrice": 100
}, {
  "Item Name": "MANCHOW NV SOUP ",
  "SellingPrice": 125
}, {
  "Item Name": "CEASER SALAD V",
  "SellingPrice": 175
}, {
  "Item Name": "CEASER SALAD NV",
  "SellingPrice": 230
}, {
  "Item Name": "GAMBUS REBOZADAS",
  "SellingPrice": 350
}, {
  "Item Name": "PANCO FISH FINGER",
  "SellingPrice": 270
}, {
  "Item Name": "MUSHROOM DUPLEX",
  "SellingPrice": 160
}, {
  "Item Name": "FRENCH FRIES",
  "SellingPrice": 99
}, {
  "Item Name": "HONEY GARLIC PRAWN",
  "SellingPrice": 350
}, {
  "Item Name": "CHICKEN MANCHURIAN",
  "SellingPrice": 180
}, {
  "Item Name": "MUSHROOM CHILLY",
  "SellingPrice": 120
}, {
  "Item Name": "SALT N PEPPER BABY CORN",
  "SellingPrice": 120
}, {
  "Item Name": "SOUTHERN STYLE CHICKEN",
  "SellingPrice": 210
}, {
  "Item Name": "PANEER NAGGETS",
  "SellingPrice": 210
}, {
  "Item Name": "HARA BHARA KEBAB",
  "SellingPrice": 160
}, {
  "Item Name": "CHICKEN TIKKA",
  "SellingPrice": 210
}, {
  "Item Name": "KALMI KEBAB",
  "SellingPrice": 250
}, {
  "Item Name": "PIZZA MARGARITTA",
  "SellingPrice": 200
}, {
  "Item Name": "PIZZA VEG FARMHOUSE",
  "SellingPrice": 200
}, {
  "Item Name": "BBQ CHICKEN PIZZA",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "CHICKEN TIKKA PIZZA",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "PESTO SAUCE",
  "SellingPrice": 175
}, {
  "Item Name": "ARABIATA",
  "SellingPrice": 160
}, {
  "Item Name": "PINK SAUCE",
  "SellingPrice": 160
}, {
  "Item Name": "GARBANZO BEAN SALAD",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "MASALA PAPAD",
  "SellingPrice": 50
}, {
  "Item Name": "PEANUT MASALA",
  "SellingPrice": 60
}, {
  "Item Name": "GAJAR KA HALWA",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "WATERMELON MARTINI",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "Kiwi martini",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": " Apple gin",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "Cucumber  cooler ",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "Martini",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "Pink lady",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": " Bloody marry",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "Cosmopolitan",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "Sex on the beach",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "Bull frog",
  "SellingPrice": 506
}, {
  "Item Name": "Long  island iced tea ",
  "SellingPrice": 393
}, {
  "Item Name": "Pinacolada",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "Daiquiri",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "Mojito ",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "Whisky sour",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "Hot toddy",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "Margarita",
  "SellingPrice": 337
}, {
  "Item Name": "Tequila sunrise",
  "SellingPrice": 337
}, {
  "Item Name": "Red sangria",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "White sangria",
  "SellingPrice": 247
}, {
  "Item Name": "Rose sangria",
  "SellingPrice": 247
}, {
  "Item Name": "By chance special ",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "Made in heaven",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "Strawberry delight",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "DRAGON",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "Mangochil ",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "Cucumber cola",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "Virgin mojito",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "Virgin mary",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "Virgin pinacolada",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "CORONA",
  "SellingPrice": 438
}, {
  "Item Name": "CRAFT BEERS",
  "SellingPrice": 337
}, {
  "Item Name": "BIRA WHITE 330",
  "SellingPrice": 157
}, {
  "Item Name": "BIRA BLONDE 330",
  "SellingPrice": 135
}, {
  "Item Name": "BIRA STRONG 650",
  "SellingPrice": 213
}, {
  "Item Name": "KINGFISHER PREMIUM 330",
  "SellingPrice": 123
}, {
  "Item Name": "KINGFISHER PREMIUM 650",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "KINGFISHER STRONG 330",
  "SellingPrice": 135
}, {
  "Item Name": "KINGFISHER STRONG 650",
  "SellingPrice": 213
}, {
  "Item Name": "KINGFISHER ULTRA 330",
  "SellingPrice": 146
}, {
  "Item Name": "KINGFISHER ULTRA 650",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "KINGFISHER ULTRA MAX 330",
  "SellingPrice": 146
}, {
  "Item Name": "KINGFISHER ULTRA MAX 650",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "BUDWIESER 330",
  "SellingPrice": 146
}, {
  "Item Name": "BUDWIESER 650",
  "SellingPrice": 270
}, {
  "Item Name": "BUDWIESER MAGNUM 330",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "BUDWIESER MAGNUM 650",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "TUBORG 330",
  "SellingPrice": 123
}, {
  "Item Name": "TUBORG 650",
  "SellingPrice": 191
}, {
  "Item Name": "TUBORG STRONG 330",
  "SellingPrice": 123
}, {
  "Item Name": "TUBORG STRONG 650",
  "SellingPrice": 213
}, {
  "Item Name": "CRANBERRY ",
  "SellingPrice": 157
}, {
  "Item Name": "ORANGE",
  "SellingPrice": 157
}, {
  "Item Name": "JAMICAN",
  "SellingPrice": 157
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK BERRY",
  "SellingPrice": 157
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLUE BERRY",
  "SellingPrice": 157
}, {
  "Item Name": "MOET CHANDON",
  "SellingPrice": 787
}, {
  "Item Name": "SULA BRUT",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "MATEUS ROSE",
  "SellingPrice": 213
}, {
  "Item Name": "HARDYS SIRAZ CABERNET 750",
  "SellingPrice": 189
}, {
  "Item Name": "HARDYS SIRAZ CABERNET BY GLASS",
  "SellingPrice": 382
}, {
  "Item Name": "JACOB CREEK SIRAZ 750",
  "SellingPrice": 180
}, {
  "Item Name": "JACOB CREEK SIRAZ BY GLASS",
  "SellingPrice": 360
}, {
  "Item Name": "BIG BANAYAN CHENNIN BLANC 750",
  "SellingPrice": 990
}, {
  "Item Name": "BIG BANAYAN CHENNI",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "SULA CHENIN BLANC 750 ",
  "SellingPrice": 129
}, {
  "Item Name": "SULA CHENIN BLANC BY GLASS",
  "SellingPrice": 258
}, {
  "Item Name": "FOUR SEAZON CLASSIC",
  "SellingPrice": 112
}, {
  "Item Name": "FOUR SEAZON CLASSIC ",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "BIG BANAYAN CARBINET ",
  "SellingPrice": 112
}, {
  "Item Name": "BIG BANAYAN CARBINE",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "SULA SATORI MERLOT 750",
  "SellingPrice": 123
}, {
  "Item Name": "SULA SATORI MERLOT BY GLASS",
  "SellingPrice": 247
}, {
  "Item Name": "GROVERS LA RESERVE 750",
  "SellingPrice": 180
}, {
  "Item Name": "GROVERS LA RESERVE 100",
  "SellingPrice": 360
}, {
  "Item Name": "GLENFIDDICH 12 YEARS 700 ",
  "SellingPrice": 922
}, {
  "Item Name": "GLENFIDDICH 12 YEARS 30",
  "SellingPrice": 405
}, {
  "Item Name": "TALISKER 750",
  "SellingPrice": 877
}, {
  "Item Name": "TALISKER 30",
  "SellingPrice": 360
}, {
  "Item Name": "GLENNLIVET 750",
  "SellingPrice": 888
}, {
  "Item Name": "GLENNLIVET 30",
  "SellingPrice": 360
}, {
  "Item Name": "THE SINGLETON 750",
  "SellingPrice": 794
}, {
  "Item Name": "THE SINGLETON 30",
  "SellingPrice": 326
}, {
  "Item Name": "AMRUT FUSION 750",
  "SellingPrice": 506
}, {
  "Item Name": "AMRUT FUSION 30",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "JACK DANIELS 750",
  "SellingPrice": 731
}, {
  "Item Name": "JACK DANIELS 30",
  "SellingPrice": 292
}, {
  "Item Name": "JIM BEAM WHITE 750",
  "SellingPrice": 409
}, {
  "Item Name": "JIM BEAM WHITE 30",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "JAMESON 750",
  "SellingPrice": 49
}, {
  "Item Name": "JAMESON 30",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "JW BLACK LABEL 750",
  "SellingPrice": 821
}, {
  "Item Name": "JW BLACK LABEL 200",
  "SellingPrice": 29
}, {
  "Item Name": "JW BLACK LABEL 30",
  "SellingPrice": 337
}, {
  "Item Name": "JW RED LABEL 200",
  "SellingPrice": 115
}, {
  "Item Name": "BALLENTINSE FINEST BLENDED 750",
  "SellingPrice": 454
}, {
  "Item Name": "BALLENTINSE FINEST BLENDED 30",
  "SellingPrice": 180
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK \u0026 WHITE 375",
  "SellingPrice": 157
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK \u0026 WHITE 180",
  "SellingPrice": 787
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK \u0026 WHITE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 258
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK \u0026 WHITE 30",
  "SellingPrice": 135
}, {
  "Item Name": "100 PIPERS 180",
  "SellingPrice": 787
}, {
  "Item Name": "100 PIPERS 60",
  "SellingPrice": 258
}, {
  "Item Name": "100 PIPERS 30",
  "SellingPrice": 135
}, {
  "Item Name": "VAT 69 180",
  "SellingPrice": 675
}, {
  "Item Name": "VAT 69 60",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "VAT 69 30",
  "SellingPrice": 112
}, {
  "Item Name": "TEACHERS HIGHLAND 180",
  "SellingPrice": 787
}, {
  "Item Name": "TEACHERS HIGHLAND 60",
  "SellingPrice": 258
}, {
  "Item Name": "TEACHERS HIGHLAND 30",
  "SellingPrice": 135
}, {
  "Item Name": "TEACHERS 50 60",
  "SellingPrice": 393
}, {
  "Item Name": "TEACHERS 50 30",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK DOG TRIPPLE GOLD 180",
  "SellingPrice": 121
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK DOG TRIPPLE GOLD 30",
  "SellingPrice": 213
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK DOG 8 YEARS 180",
  "SellingPrice": 731
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK DOG 8 YEARS 60",
  "SellingPrice": 247
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK DOG 8 YEARS 30",
  "SellingPrice": 123
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLENDERS PRIDE 750",
  "SellingPrice": 228
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLENDERS PRIDE 375",
  "SellingPrice": 114
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLENDERS PRIDE 180",
  "SellingPrice": 573
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLENDERS PRIDE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 191
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLENDERS PRIDE 30",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "SIGNATURE 180",
  "SellingPrice": 450
}, {
  "Item Name": "SIGNATURE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "SIGNATURE 30",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "GREY GOOSE 750",
  "SellingPrice": 819
}, {
  "Item Name": "GREY GOOSE 30",
  "SellingPrice": 326
}, {
  "Item Name": "BELVEDERE 700",
  "SellingPrice": 812
}, {
  "Item Name": "BELVEDERE 30",
  "SellingPrice": 360
}, {
  "Item Name": "CIROC 750",
  "SellingPrice": 742
}, {
  "Item Name": "CIROC 30",
  "SellingPrice": 303
}, {
  "Item Name": "ABSOLUT 750",
  "SellingPrice": 455
}, {
  "Item Name": "ABSOLUT 30",
  "SellingPrice": 191
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF RED 180",
  "SellingPrice": 551
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF RED 60",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF RED30",
  "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF ORANGE 180",
  "SellingPrice": 551
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF ORANGE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMINOFF ORANGE30",
  "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF GREEN APPLE 180",
  "SellingPrice": 551
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF GREEN APPLE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF GREEN APPLE30",
  "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
  "Item Name": "BOMBAY SAPHIRE 750",
  "SellingPrice": 472
}, {
  "Item Name": "BOMBAY SAPHIRE 30",
  "SellingPrice": 191
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLUE RIBBAND 750",
  "SellingPrice": 877
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLUE RIBBAND 60",
  "SellingPrice": 78
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI WHITE 750",
  "SellingPrice": 248
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI WHITE 180",
  "SellingPrice": 585
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI WHITE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI WHITE 30",
  "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI LEMON 180",
  "SellingPrice": 585
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI LEMON 60",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI LEMON 30",
  "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI ORANGE 180",
  "SellingPrice": 585
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI ORANGE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI LEMON 30",
  "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI BLACK 180",
  "SellingPrice": 393
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI BLACK 30",
  "SellingPrice": 67
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI GOLD 180",
  "SellingPrice": 585
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI GOLD30",
  "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
  "Item Name": "OLD MONK 180",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "OLD MONK 90",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "OLD MONK 60",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "OLD MONK 30 ",
  "SellingPrice": 45
}, {
  "Item Name": "DON ANGEL 750",
  "SellingPrice": 466
}, {
  "Item Name": "DON ANGEL 30",
  "SellingPrice": 191
}, {
  "Item Name": "SAUZA SILVER 700",
  "SellingPrice": 615
}, {
  "Item Name": "SAUZA SILVER 30",
  "SellingPrice": 270
}, {
  "Item Name": "JAGERBOMB",
  "SellingPrice": 506
}, {
  "Item Name": "KAMAKAZI",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "JAGERMASTER",
  "SellingPrice": 303
}, {
  "Item Name": "COINTTRAEU",
  "SellingPrice": 303
}, {
  "Item Name": "SAMBUCA",
  "SellingPrice": 258
}, {
  "Item Name": "KHALUA",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "MARTINI BLANCO",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "MARTINI ROSSO",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "HENESSY VS 700",
  "SellingPrice": 787
}, {
  "Item Name": "HENESSY VS 30",
  "SellingPrice": 348
}, {
  "Item Name": "MORPHEUS 750",
  "SellingPrice": 218
}, {
  "Item Name": "MORPHEUS 180",
  "SellingPrice": 540
}, {
  "Item Name": "MORPHEUS 60",
  "SellingPrice": 191
}, {
  "Item Name": "MORPHEUS 30",
  "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
  "Item Name": "MANSION HOUSE 180",
  "SellingPrice": 292
}, {
  "Item Name": "MANSION HOUSE 90",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "MANSION HOUSE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "MC BRANDY 60",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "RED BULL ",
  "SellingPrice": 157
}, {
  "Item Name": "COKE",
  "SellingPrice": 45
}, {
  "Item Name": "SPRITE",
  "SellingPrice": 45
}, {
  "Item Name": "SODA",
  "SellingPrice": 33
}, {
  "Item Name": "DIET COKE",
  "SellingPrice": 56
}, {
  "Item Name": "TONIC WATER",
  "SellingPrice": 67
}, {
  "Item Name": "GINGER ALE",
  "SellingPrice": 67
}, {
  "Item Name": "LIME SODA",
  "SellingPrice": 45
}, {
  "Item Name": "LIME WATER",
  "SellingPrice": 45
}, {
  "Item Name": "PACKEGED WATER 1L",
  "SellingPrice": 39
}, {
  "Item Name": "MANSION HOUSE 650",
  "SellingPrice": 900
}, {
  "Item Name": "Chole Kulche",
  "SellingPrice": 80
}, {
  "Item Name": "Butter Nan",
  "SellingPrice": 65
}, {
  "Item Name": "Dhai",
  "SellingPrice": 20
}, {
  "Item Name": "Rice",
  "SellingPrice": 55
}, {
  "Item Name": "Plain rice",
  "SellingPrice": 30
}, {
  "Item Name": "MANSION HOUSE 650",
  "SellingPrice": 900
}, {
  "Item Name": "Chole Kulche",
  "SellingPrice": 80
}, {
  "Item Name": "Butter Nan",
  "SellingPrice": 65
}, {
  "Item Name": "Dhai",
  "SellingPrice": 20
}, {
  "Item Name": "Rice",
  "SellingPrice": 55
}, {
  "Item Name": "Plain rice",
  "SellingPrice": 30
}]

interval = '';

function initTable(tableValue) {
  addTable(tableValue)
  interval = window.setInterval(showRows, 3000);
}

initTable(tableValue);


function hideImage() {
  //  5000 = 5 seconds
  window.setInterval(doHide, 3000);
}

function doHide() {
  $("#displayImage").show() //this is here I am trying to show image
}




function showRows() {
  // Any TRs that are not hidden and not already shown get "already-shown" applies
  if ($(".hidden:lt(12)").length > 0) { //checking is it is the last page or not
    $("tr:not(.hidden):not(.already-shown)").addClass("already-shown");
  } else { // if it is the last row
    $("tr:not(.hidden):not(.already-shown)").addClass("already-shown");

    hideImage();
    //
    clearInterval(interval); //if last then clearing time interval and calling the function again 
    initTable(tableValue);
  }

  $(".hidden:lt(12)").removeClass("hidden"); // this one is to hide previous  rows and show next 
}

function addTable(tableValue) {
  var $tbl = $("<table />", {
      "class": "table fixed"
    }),
    $tb = $("<tbody/>"),
    $trh = $("<tr/>");

  var split = Math.round(tableValue.length / 4);
  for (i = 0; i < split; i++) {
    $tr = $("<tr/>", {
      class: "hidden "
    });

    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      $.each(tableValue[split * j + i], function(key, value) {
        if (typeof(value) === "number") {
          $("<td/>", {
            "class": "text-right color" + (j + 1)
          }).html(value).appendTo($tr);
        } else {
          $("<td/>", {
            "class": "text-left color" + (j + 1)
          }).html(value).appendTo($tr);
        }

      });
    }
    $tr.appendTo($tb);
  }
  $tbl.append($tb);
  $("#DisplayTable").html($tbl);
}
```

```css
tbody>tr>td {
  white-space: normal;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: .9em;
}

td:nth-child(2),
td:nth-child(4),
td:nth-child(6),
td:nth-child(8) {
  width: 85px;
  max-width: 85px;
  height: 63px
}

.fixed {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.color1 {
  background: #4AD184;
}

.color2 {
  background: #EA69EF;
}

.color3 {
  background: #E1A558;
}

.color4 {
  background: #F4F065;
}

.hidden,
.already-shown {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="DisplayTable"></div>
<div id="displayImage" style="display: none">

  <img src="myImage.jpg" alt="Some Image" width="460" height="345">
</div>
```

**Edit / Update**

I have edit my snippet, With some code image is showing put it is showing below the table not after the last page and also it is not getting hide once it is showing up then it is showing up only

Comment: when your image is visible your table needs to be hidden right?

Comment: @SyedMohamedAladeen yes if you understood the flow correctly then when first time full table loaded then show Image and after that show table again

Comment: hey @manishthakur could you please confirm me....

after reaching the last page you want to show the image for 10secs only then image should be hide right?

Comment: instead of showing data after last page you want to show image right then after 10 mins again data has to come as it is....correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @SoubhagyaKumar yup that time will be 10 or 15 seconds it will depend on user , when  there is last Page then after that show image for some time and then same process again

Comment: so my question is after reaching last page only image has to display then after 10 secs image will be hide and data will show again 


correct me if i am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. I have updated your hide image code.

```js
var tableValue = [{
  "Item Name": "MANCHOW  V SOUP",
  "SellingPrice": 100
}, {
  "Item Name": "MANCHOW NV SOUP ",
  "SellingPrice": 125
}, {
  "Item Name": "CEASER SALAD V",
  "SellingPrice": 175
}, {
  "Item Name": "CEASER SALAD NV",
  "SellingPrice": 230
}, {
  "Item Name": "GAMBUS REBOZADAS",
  "SellingPrice": 350
}, {
  "Item Name": "PANCO FISH FINGER",
  "SellingPrice": 270
}, {
  "Item Name": "MUSHROOM DUPLEX",
  "SellingPrice": 160
}, {
  "Item Name": "FRENCH FRIES",
  "SellingPrice": 99
}, {
  "Item Name": "HONEY GARLIC PRAWN",
  "SellingPrice": 350
}, {
  "Item Name": "CHICKEN MANCHURIAN",
  "SellingPrice": 180
}, {
  "Item Name": "MUSHROOM CHILLY",
  "SellingPrice": 120
}, {
  "Item Name": "SALT N PEPPER BABY CORN",
  "SellingPrice": 120
}, {
  "Item Name": "SOUTHERN STYLE CHICKEN",
  "SellingPrice": 210
}, {
  "Item Name": "PANEER NAGGETS",
  "SellingPrice": 210
}, {
  "Item Name": "HARA BHARA KEBAB",
  "SellingPrice": 160
}, {
  "Item Name": "CHICKEN TIKKA",
  "SellingPrice": 210
}, {
  "Item Name": "KALMI KEBAB",
  "SellingPrice": 250
}, {
  "Item Name": "PIZZA MARGARITTA",
  "SellingPrice": 200
}, {
  "Item Name": "PIZZA VEG FARMHOUSE",
  "SellingPrice": 200
}, {
  "Item Name": "BBQ CHICKEN PIZZA",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "CHICKEN TIKKA PIZZA",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "PESTO SAUCE",
  "SellingPrice": 175
}, {
  "Item Name": "ARABIATA",
  "SellingPrice": 160
}, {
  "Item Name": "PINK SAUCE",
  "SellingPrice": 160
}, {
  "Item Name": "GARBANZO BEAN SALAD",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "MASALA PAPAD",
  "SellingPrice": 50
}, {
  "Item Name": "PEANUT MASALA",
  "SellingPrice": 60
}, {
  "Item Name": "GAJAR KA HALWA",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "WATERMELON MARTINI",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "Kiwi martini",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": " Apple gin",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "Cucumber  cooler ",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "Martini",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "Pink lady",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": " Bloody marry",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "Cosmopolitan",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "the beach",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "Bull frog",
  "SellingPrice": 506
}, {
  "Item Name": "Long  island iced tea ",
  "SellingPrice": 393
}, {
  "Item Name": "Pinacolada",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "Daiquiri",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "Mojito ",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "Whisky sour",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "Hot toddy",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "Margarita",
  "SellingPrice": 337
}, {
  "Item Name": "Tequila sunrise",
  "SellingPrice": 337
}, {
  "Item Name": "Red sangria",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "White sangria",
  "SellingPrice": 247
}, {
  "Item Name": "Rose sangria",
  "SellingPrice": 247
}, {
  "Item Name": "By chance special ",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "Made in heaven",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "Strawberry delight",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "DRAGON",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "Mangochil ",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "Cucumber cola",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "Virgin mojito",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "Virgin mary",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "Virgin pinacolada",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "CORONA",
  "SellingPrice": 438
}, {
  "Item Name": "CRAFT BEERS",
  "SellingPrice": 337
}, {
  "Item Name": "BIRA WHITE 330",
  "SellingPrice": 157
}, {
  "Item Name": "BIRA BLONDE 330",
  "SellingPrice": 135
}, {
  "Item Name": "BIRA STRONG 650",
  "SellingPrice": 213
}, {
  "Item Name": "KINGFISHER PREMIUM 330",
  "SellingPrice": 123
}, {
  "Item Name": "KINGFISHER PREMIUM 650",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "KINGFISHER STRONG 330",
  "SellingPrice": 135
}, {
  "Item Name": "KINGFISHER STRONG 650",
  "SellingPrice": 213
}, {
  "Item Name": "KINGFISHER ULTRA 330",
  "SellingPrice": 146
}, {
  "Item Name": "KINGFISHER ULTRA 650",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "KINGFISHER ULTRA MAX 330",
  "SellingPrice": 146
}, {
  "Item Name": "KINGFISHER ULTRA MAX 650",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "BUDWIESER 330",
  "SellingPrice": 146
}, {
  "Item Name": "BUDWIESER 650",
  "SellingPrice": 270
}, {
  "Item Name": "BUDWIESER MAGNUM 330",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "BUDWIESER MAGNUM 650",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "TUBORG 330",
  "SellingPrice": 123
}, {
  "Item Name": "TUBORG 650",
  "SellingPrice": 191
}, {
  "Item Name": "TUBORG STRONG 330",
  "SellingPrice": 123
}, {
  "Item Name": "TUBORG STRONG 650",
  "SellingPrice": 213
}, {
  "Item Name": "CRANBERRY ",
  "SellingPrice": 157
}, {
  "Item Name": "ORANGE",
  "SellingPrice": 157
}, {
  "Item Name": "JAMICAN",
  "SellingPrice": 157
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK BERRY",
  "SellingPrice": 157
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLUE BERRY",
  "SellingPrice": 157
}, {
  "Item Name": "MOET CHANDON",
  "SellingPrice": 787
}, {
  "Item Name": "SULA BRUT",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "MATEUS ROSE",
  "SellingPrice": 213
}, {
  "Item Name": "HARDYS SIRAZ CABERNET 750",
  "SellingPrice": 189
}, {
  "Item Name": "HARDYS SIRAZ CABERNET BY GLASS",
  "SellingPrice": 382
}, {
  "Item Name": "JACOB CREEK SIRAZ 750",
  "SellingPrice": 180
}, {
  "Item Name": "JACOB CREEK SIRAZ BY GLASS",
  "SellingPrice": 360
}, {
  "Item Name": "BIG BANAYAN CHENNIN BLANC 750",
  "SellingPrice": 990
}, {
  "Item Name": "BIG BANAYAN CHENNI",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "SULA CHENIN BLANC 750 ",
  "SellingPrice": 129
}, {
  "Item Name": "SULA CHENIN BLANC BY GLASS",
  "SellingPrice": 258
}, {
  "Item Name": "FOUR SEAZON CLASSIC",
  "SellingPrice": 112
}, {
  "Item Name": "FOUR SEAZON CLASSIC ",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "BIG BANAYAN CARBINET ",
  "SellingPrice": 112
}, {
  "Item Name": "BIG BANAYAN CARBINE",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "SULA SATORI MERLOT 750",
  "SellingPrice": 123
}, {
  "Item Name": "SULA SATORI MERLOT BY GLASS",
  "SellingPrice": 247
}, {
  "Item Name": "GROVERS LA RESERVE 750",
  "SellingPrice": 180
}, {
  "Item Name": "GROVERS LA RESERVE 100",
  "SellingPrice": 360
}, {
  "Item Name": "GLENFIDDICH 12 YEARS 700 ",
  "SellingPrice": 922
}, {
  "Item Name": "GLENFIDDICH 12 YEARS 30",
  "SellingPrice": 405
}, {
  "Item Name": "TALISKER 750",
  "SellingPrice": 877
}, {
  "Item Name": "TALISKER 30",
  "SellingPrice": 360
}, {
  "Item Name": "GLENNLIVET 750",
  "SellingPrice": 888
}, {
  "Item Name": "GLENNLIVET 30",
  "SellingPrice": 360
}, {
  "Item Name": "THE SINGLETON 750",
  "SellingPrice": 794
}, {
  "Item Name": "THE SINGLETON 30",
  "SellingPrice": 326
}, {
  "Item Name": "AMRUT FUSION 750",
  "SellingPrice": 506
}, {
  "Item Name": "AMRUT FUSION 30",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "JACK DANIELS 750",
  "SellingPrice": 731
}, {
  "Item Name": "JACK DANIELS 30",
  "SellingPrice": 292
}, {
  "Item Name": "JIM BEAM WHITE 750",
  "SellingPrice": 409
}, {
  "Item Name": "JIM BEAM WHITE 30",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "JAMESON 750",
  "SellingPrice": 49
}, {
  "Item Name": "JAMESON 30",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "JW BLACK LABEL 750",
  "SellingPrice": 821
}, {
  "Item Name": "JW BLACK LABEL 200",
  "SellingPrice": 29
}, {
  "Item Name": "JW BLACK LABEL 30",
  "SellingPrice": 337
}, {
  "Item Name": "JW RED LABEL 200",
  "SellingPrice": 115
}, {
  "Item Name": "BALLENTINSE FINEST BLENDED 750",
  "SellingPrice": 454
}, {
  "Item Name": "BALLENTINSE FINEST BLENDED 30",
  "SellingPrice": 180
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK \u0026 WHITE 375",
  "SellingPrice": 157
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK \u0026 WHITE 180",
  "SellingPrice": 787
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK \u0026 WHITE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 258
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK \u0026 WHITE 30",
  "SellingPrice": 135
}, {
  "Item Name": "100 PIPERS 180",
  "SellingPrice": 787
}, {
  "Item Name": "100 PIPERS 60",
  "SellingPrice": 258
}, {
  "Item Name": "100 PIPERS 30",
  "SellingPrice": 135
}, {
  "Item Name": "VAT 69 180",
  "SellingPrice": 675
}, {
  "Item Name": "VAT 69 60",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "VAT 69 30",
  "SellingPrice": 112
}, {
  "Item Name": "TEACHERS HIGHLAND 180",
  "SellingPrice": 787
}, {
  "Item Name": "TEACHERS HIGHLAND 60",
  "SellingPrice": 258
}, {
  "Item Name": "TEACHERS HIGHLAND 30",
  "SellingPrice": 135
}, {
  "Item Name": "TEACHERS 50 60",
  "SellingPrice": 393
}, {
  "Item Name": "TEACHERS 50 30",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK DOG TRIPPLE GOLD 180",
  "SellingPrice": 121
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK DOG TRIPPLE GOLD 30",
  "SellingPrice": 213
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK DOG 8 YEARS 180",
  "SellingPrice": 731
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK DOG 8 YEARS 60",
  "SellingPrice": 247
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK DOG 8 YEARS 30",
  "SellingPrice": 123
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLENDERS PRIDE 750",
  "SellingPrice": 228
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLENDERS PRIDE 375",
  "SellingPrice": 114
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLENDERS PRIDE 180",
  "SellingPrice": 573
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLENDERS PRIDE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 191
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLENDERS PRIDE 30",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "SIGNATURE 180",
  "SellingPrice": 450
}, {
  "Item Name": "SIGNATURE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "SIGNATURE 30",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "GREY GOOSE 750",
  "SellingPrice": 819
}, {
  "Item Name": "GREY GOOSE 30",
  "SellingPrice": 326
}, {
  "Item Name": "BELVEDERE 700",
  "SellingPrice": 812
}, {
  "Item Name": "BELVEDERE 30",
  "SellingPrice": 360
}, {
  "Item Name": "CIROC 750",
  "SellingPrice": 742
}, {
  "Item Name": "CIROC 30",
  "SellingPrice": 303
}, {
  "Item Name": "ABSOLUT 750",
  "SellingPrice": 455
}, {
  "Item Name": "ABSOLUT 30",
  "SellingPrice": 191
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF RED 180",
  "SellingPrice": 551
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF RED 60",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF RED30",
  "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF ORANGE 180",
  "SellingPrice": 551
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF ORANGE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMINOFF ORANGE30",
  "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF GREEN APPLE 180",
  "SellingPrice": 551
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF GREEN APPLE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF GREEN APPLE30",
  "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
  "Item Name": "BOMBAY SAPHIRE 750",
  "SellingPrice": 472
}, {
  "Item Name": "BOMBAY SAPHIRE 30",
  "SellingPrice": 191
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLUE RIBBAND 750",
  "SellingPrice": 877
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLUE RIBBAND 60",
  "SellingPrice": 78
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI WHITE 750",
  "SellingPrice": 248
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI WHITE 180",
  "SellingPrice": 585
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI WHITE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI WHITE 30",
  "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI LEMON 180",
  "SellingPrice": 585
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI LEMON 60",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI LEMON 30",
  "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI ORANGE 180",
  "SellingPrice": 585
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI ORANGE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI LEMON 30",
  "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI BLACK 180",
  "SellingPrice": 393
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI BLACK 30",
  "SellingPrice": 67
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI GOLD 180",
  "SellingPrice": 585
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI GOLD30",
  "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
  "Item Name": "OLD MONK 180",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "OLD MONK 90",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "OLD MONK 60",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "OLD MONK 30 ",
  "SellingPrice": 45
}, {
  "Item Name": "DON ANGEL 750",
  "SellingPrice": 466
}, {
  "Item Name": "DON ANGEL 30",
  "SellingPrice": 191
}, {
  "Item Name": "SAUZA SILVER 700",
  "SellingPrice": 615
}, {
  "Item Name": "SAUZA SILVER 30",
  "SellingPrice": 270
}, {
  "Item Name": "JAGERBOMB",
  "SellingPrice": 506
}, {
  "Item Name": "KAMAKAZI",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "JAGERMASTER",
  "SellingPrice": 303
}, {
  "Item Name": "COINTTRAEU",
  "SellingPrice": 303
}, {
  "Item Name": "SAMBUCA",
  "SellingPrice": 258
}, {
  "Item Name": "KHALUA",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "MARTINI BLANCO",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "MARTINI ROSSO",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "HENESSY VS 700",
  "SellingPrice": 787
}, {
  "Item Name": "HENESSY VS 30",
  "SellingPrice": 348
}, {
  "Item Name": "MORPHEUS 750",
  "SellingPrice": 218
}, {
  "Item Name": "MORPHEUS 180",
  "SellingPrice": 540
}, {
  "Item Name": "MORPHEUS 60",
  "SellingPrice": 191
}, {
  "Item Name": "MORPHEUS 30",
  "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
  "Item Name": "MANSION HOUSE 180",
  "SellingPrice": 292
}, {
  "Item Name": "MANSION HOUSE 90",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "MANSION HOUSE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "MC BRANDY 60",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "RED BULL ",
  "SellingPrice": 157
}, {
  "Item Name": "COKE",
  "SellingPrice": 45
}, {
  "Item Name": "SPRITE",
  "SellingPrice": 45
}, {
  "Item Name": "SODA",
  "SellingPrice": 33
}, {
  "Item Name": "DIET COKE",
  "SellingPrice": 56
}, {
  "Item Name": "TONIC WATER",
  "SellingPrice": 67
}, {
  "Item Name": "GINGER ALE",
  "SellingPrice": 67
}, {
  "Item Name": "LIME SODA",
  "SellingPrice": 45
}, {
  "Item Name": "LIME WATER",
  "SellingPrice": 45
}, {
  "Item Name": "PACKEGED WATER 1L",
  "SellingPrice": 39
}, {
  "Item Name": "MANSION HOUSE 650",
  "SellingPrice": 900
}, {
  "Item Name": "Chole Kulche",
  "SellingPrice": 80
}, {
  "Item Name": "Butter Nan",
  "SellingPrice": 65
}, {
  "Item Name": "Dhai",
  "SellingPrice": 20
}, {
  "Item Name": "Rice",
  "SellingPrice": 55
}, {
  "Item Name": "Plain rice",
  "SellingPrice": 30
}, {
  "Item Name": "MANSION HOUSE 650",
  "SellingPrice": 900
}, {
  "Item Name": "Chole Kulche",
  "SellingPrice": 80
}, {
  "Item Name": "Butter Nan",
  "SellingPrice": 65
}, {
  "Item Name": "Dhai",
  "SellingPrice": 20
}, {
  "Item Name": "Rice",
  "SellingPrice": 55
}, {
  "Item Name": "Plain rice",
  "SellingPrice": 30
}]

interval = '';

function initTable(tableValue) {
  addTable(tableValue)
  interval = window.setInterval(showRows, 3000);
}

initTable(tableValue);


function hideImage() {
    $("#displayImage").show(); //this is here I am trying to show image
  $("#DisplayTable").hide();
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    initTable(tableValue);
  },10000);
}





function showRows() {
  // Any TRs that are not hidden and not already shown get "already-shown" applies
  if ($(".hidden:lt(12)").length > 0) { //checking is it is the last page or not
  $("#displayImage").hide(); //this is here I am trying to show image
  $("#DisplayTable").show();
    $("tr:not(.hidden):not(.already-shown)").addClass("already-shown");
  } else { // if it is the last row
    $("tr:not(.hidden):not(.already-shown)").addClass("already-shown");

    hideImage();
    //
    clearInterval(interval); //if last then clearing time interval and calling the function again 
  }

  $(".hidden:lt(12)").removeClass("hidden"); // this one is to hide previous  rows and show next 
}

function addTable(tableValue) {
  var $tbl = $("<table />", {
      "class": "table fixed"
    }),
    $tb = $("<tbody/>"),
    $trh = $("<tr/>");

  var split = Math.round(tableValue.length / 4);
  for (i = 0; i < split; i++) {
    $tr = $("<tr/>", {
      class: "hidden "
    });

    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      $.each(tableValue[split * j + i], function(key, value) {
        if (typeof(value) === "number") {
          $("<td/>", {
            "class": "text-right color" + (j + 1)
          }).html(value).appendTo($tr);
        } else {
          $("<td/>", {
            "class": "text-left color" + (j + 1)
          }).html(value).appendTo($tr);
        }

      });
    }
    $tr.appendTo($tb);
  }
  $tbl.append($tb);
  $("#DisplayTable").html($tbl);
}
```

```css
tbody>tr>td {
  white-space: normal;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: .9em;
}

td:nth-child(2),
td:nth-child(4),
td:nth-child(6),
td:nth-child(8) {
  width: 85px;
  max-width: 85px;
  height: 63px
}

.fixed {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.color1 {
  background: #4AD184;
}

.color2 {
  background: #EA69EF;
}

.color3 {
  background: #E1A558;
}

.color4 {
  background: #F4F065;
}

.hidden,
.already-shown {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="DisplayTable"></div>
<div id="displayImage" style="display: none">

  <img src="myImage.jpg" alt="Some Image" width="460" height="345">
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dtj30ocx/1/  please check this out in this in pace of  `tableValue` I have ajax call and in success I am getting that table value and the ajax call is in the function `myFun`

Comment: This fiddle has no `tableValue`  json

Comment: Yup it will not have Because I am showing you up how I am doing it dynamically check that function myFun()  that have ajax call and `tableValue` has JSON

Comment: ajax call itself not happening here. see errors in console

Comment: hey sir I have some issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56521258/how-to-display-image-dynamically-on-ui on this post it is almost the same question on which you have helped me that's why I am asking you for some help

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the latest code below please check once.

explanation:

i have removed `hideImage()`&`doHide()`

in toggleImage() it will show the image and hide after 10 seconds

for me its working 100% please check and let me know

in showRows() if page reaching at last page then it will clear the interval time and set it to 7 seconds (10 seconds for image - 3 seconds delay)

```
 function toggleImage() {
        $("#displayImage").show();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#displayImage").hide();
        }, 10000);
    }

    function showRows() {
        // Any TRs that are not hidden and not already shown get "already-shown" applies
        if ($(".hidden:lt(12)").length > 0) { //checking is it is the last page or not
            $("tr:not(.hidden):not(.already-shown)").addClass("already-shown");
        } else { // if it is the last row
            $("tr:not(.hidden):not(.already-shown)").addClass("already-shown");
            toggleImage();
            //
            clearInterval(interval); //if last then clearing time interval and calling the function again 
            interval = false;
            setTimeout(function () {
                initTable(tableValue);
            }, 7000);
        }
        $(".hidden:lt(12)").removeClass("hidden"); // this one is to hide previous  rows and show next 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //execute your main code through ajax ajaxCall() function which will execute after every 5 seconds
    setInterval("ajaxCall()",5000);

    function ajaxCall(){
      //Your main code here
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I have done this already ,facing issue to display image when full table lodes please check my snippet